# Could someone explain a function wrapping idiom from howtonode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, node.js-connect

I have recently started working with node.js, express & mongodb. Since express uses connect to provide middleware support, I started reading up on middleware and connect.

I came across the following example on [howtonode.org](http://howtonode.org/connect-it):

```
return function logItHandle(req, res, next) {
 var writeHead = res.writeHead; // Store the original function

 counter++;

 // Log the incoming request
 console.log("Request " + counter + " " + req.method + " " + req.url);

 // Wrap writeHead to hook into the exit path through the layers.
 res.writeHead = function (code, headers) {
   res.writeHead = writeHead; // Put the original back

   // Log the outgoing response
   console.log("Response " + counter + " " + code + " " + JSON.stringify(headers));

   res.writeHead(code, headers); // Call the original
 };

 // Pass through to the next layer
 next(); 
};
```

Could someone explain to me what is happening in this closure? The author calls it a

> *wrapping idiom to hook into the call to writeHead*

What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intercepting calls to `res.writeHead`, adding some logging and then delegating calls to the original `res.writeHead`.

It's like a super-simple take on AOP for method interception.

Comment: Thanks both guys! I'm accepting @matt 's answer only because not only did it explain what was happening but it led me to AOP and now I've some new material to work on as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose what is happening here

```
wrapping idiom to hook into the call to writeHead
```

In a standard *express* flow, the request (**req**) is received and the response (**res**) is prepared. The (**req**, **res**) pair can be cascaded through a serie of filters that can modify the **req** and prepare the **res**.

At one point in the flow, the **res** will be deemed sufficiently prepared that the headers of the response can be sent to the client. The function *res.writeHead** will be called for that purpose.

The prototype of this function being *function (code, headers)*, in order to log the headers that are going to be sent, you need to hook the code at this very moment and do a

```
console.log("Response " + code + " " + JSON.stringify(headers));
```

In a way, if the orgininal function in the code was

```
res.writeHead = function(code, headers) {
    // original code
}
```

you would like to replace this code with a

```
res.writeHead = function(code, headers) {
    console.log("Response " + code + " " + JSON.stringify(headers));
    // original code
}
```

In a way, you want on "insert" a snippet of code at the beginning of the writeHead function.

But you should not try and modify the original writeHead code, because you might not even know where this code is written and you don't want to start looking. So you want to hijack this function : When a piece of code will call res.writeHead, you want your function to be called instead.

A way to to this is simply

```
return function logItHandle(req, res, next) {
   res.writeHead = function (code, headers) {
       console.log("Response " + code + " " + JSON.stringify(headers));
   }
   next(); 
}
```

but if you only do this you're into a bit of a trouble because the original writeHead code is lost and will not be called. Hence the headers will be logged but not sent to the client !

you need a way to "remember" the original code and call it at the end of you writeHead variant :

```
return function logItHandle(req, res, next) {

   // save the original writeHead function so that it can be referenced in the closure
   var originalWriteHead = res.writeHead; 

   res.writeHead = function (code, headers) {

       // log the response headers
       console.log("Response " + code + " " + JSON.stringify(headers));

       // make as if our hook never existed in the flow
       res.writeHead = originalWriteHead ;

       // call the original writeHead because otherwise the external code
       // called our implementation of writeHead instead of the original code
       res.writeHead(code, headers);

   }
   next(); 
}
```